# How to install mongodb-clients latest version on Ubuntu?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

How do I install latest version of `mongodb-clients` on Ubuntu using `apt-get`?

`apt-get install mongodb-clients` only installs version `2.4.9`.

Comment: Thanks, I did the steps on the docs already, but the package name is `mongodb-org-tools` instead of `mongodb-clients`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

On Ubuntu 16.04 to get the 4.2 mongo client

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org-shell
```

Comment: @alexander ,how to open this tool in ubuntu.I have installed successfully but not able to open it.

Comment: @akgola here's a list of all tools included https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04: 
echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list

Comment: @akgola one could start the mongo shell by issuing `mongo`

Comment: @georgeos you are missing `https://` in that deb URL

Comment: Thank you! For ubuntu 20 this worked perfectly well for me:

`wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -
&& 
echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
&& 
sudo apt-get update
&&
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org-shell`

Comment: Official doc provide guid for each use-cases: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 4):

Use official MongoDB Documents they already mentioned how to install a version of your choice. [Steps for installation for Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

For Ubuntu 16.04 use [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04)

***NOTE:-*** Before that beware that you don't have any existing repository file for MongoDB. You can check using `sudo apt-get update`.While updating it will show if you have any. If you have then delete it using `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb*.list` and then install MongoDB

Answer (score 3):

For mongodb 3.2, below packages are supported. In order to use mongo shell, you need to install mongo-org-shell. Choose the right package according to your requreiements.
[install mongodb on ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One could install a mongodb shell on Ubuntu by following [these instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) or by using an Ansible like [image: Ansible Galaxy].

At the time of writing, this ansible role installed version 4.2.5 of the mongo shell:

```
user@some-host:~/some-dir$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v4.2.5
git version: x
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL y
allocator: z
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1804
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

Answer (score -1):

20.04 focal is not setup yet, but you can use the instructions for bionic (18.04) successfully. I did!
Ray.

Comment: Pasting the instructions and adding a link to the docs might help make this a complete answer, and easier for people coming across this problem in the future